# Copy List<A> items to List<B> items using Java stream API

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I am trying copy list elements from `List<A>` to `List<B>` and facing some type error.

My code:

```
   List<AttachmentTypeDto> attachmentTypeList=clientDetails.getAttachmentTypeDto();
   List<ClientAttachmentTypeEntity> mappedAttachmentList=attachmentTypeList.stream().map(temp ->{

      ClientAttachmentTypeEntity toAttachmentObject=new ClientAttachmentTypeEntity();
      toAttachmentObject.setAttachmentTypeId(temp.getAttachmentTypeId());
      toAttachmentObject.setClientId(temp.getClientId());

  }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It gives me error like this:

```
The method map(Function<? super AttachmentTypeDto,? extends R>) in the type Stream<AttachmentTypeDto> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> temp) -> {})
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: i don't understand why someone has voted -1

Comment: you should return `toAttachmentObject` in the map function. `.map(temp->{ ... return toAttachmentObject;}) ...`

Comment: this really solved  my problem , thanks  @Hadi J

Comment: A remark: I would suggest to extract the mapping process (i.e. the lambda-body within `.map(...)` in separate method, e.g. `convertAttachmentDtoToClientAttachmentDto(...)` and then call `map(this::convertAttachmentDtoToClientAttachmentDto)`.

Comment: great , i was working on same solution  :)